# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it--Socket C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient

Hi guys i'm trying to build a server-client app in c#.it is working on local but i want to work it through internet bu i have this error when i entered my ip:

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Checked that my firewall is off.

here is my code.i wish you could help..

[image]

Comment: What is the IP address of the target machine?

Comment: Are you using a router with NAT? If so, did you set up port forwarding properly?

Comment: Is your machine and the remote client/server on the same network, or truly across the internet?

Comment: i have tried both but currently my computer is server  and client itself.

Comment: Try it with the ip address `127.0.0.1` if both the client and server are on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

When testing connectivity there are few simple steps for basic testing.

- try to ping target machine
- if target machine is local one, then use 127.0.0.1 address if all other addresses fail
- disable your firewall
- check that server service/application is started
- try to telnet to address and port of that service to see if port is open
- make sure that no other application is holding the port open. You can do this using `netstat` utility

In your specific case it looks to me like you are trying to connect to your router rather than machine you are hosting application on. Do `ipconfig /all` in Command prompt to see all IP address your machine has.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi guys i'm trying to build a server-client app in c#

Were you aware of [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) and in particular the short example demonstrating the most basic functionality [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/952f51c14671/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs)? This was written specifically for people writing server-client apps in c# and given most of the problems you might come across will already have been solved and it might save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

you sure you can get to your target machine?  If its a server sitting directly on the internet, most likely the server application isn't running or its being blocked by the machine  ( or sometimes the hosting company has an extra firewall you have to open, like on amazon).    If its just another machine connect via an ISP, then it will most likely be going through NAT as it hits your router and you can't make direct connections this easily.

Comment: how can i do then ? could you link an example?

Comment: what do you mean?i'm beginner in socket programming

Answer (score 0):

The link has the complete example of a Socket programming which acts as a FTP. The program checks for the size of the file and if it is larger than 1MB, it will split the files and merge at the destination folder.

PS: You code is not the best you can get. There can be a lot of improvements on it. It is from one of my old blogs which I have not updated. 
http://vinayhoskere.blogspot.com/2010/11/file-transfer-using-socket-programming.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are reaching the target machine, but nothing is there to handle your connection.